# Casting to ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> when saving List in onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, list, arraylist, parcelable, onsaveinstancestate

I coulnd't find an answer on that:

I want to save a Parcelable ArrayList in onSaveInstanceState, but it does not accept an ArrayList that is declared as a List when I do it like this:

```
outState.putParcelableArrayList(KEY_QUESTION_LIST, questionList);
```

So I have 2 options: Either declaring the List as an ArrayList or casting it into a Parcelable ArrayList like this:

```
outState.putParcelableArrayList(KEY_QUESTION_LIST, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) questionList);
```

and keeping it declared as a List:

```
private List<Question> questionList;
```

Online I only see the first approach so I wonder if there are any downsides to the 2nd approach?

Comment: Do you plan on using any other subclass of List interface that isn't an Arraylist?

Comment: No, it is just a small app and will only use this ArrayList

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your list is declared like this:

```
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

There is no *problem* if you want to later write `(ArrayList) list`. However, I think this is a worse choice overall than simply declaring your list as an ArrayList to begin with:

```
ArrayList<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

As Java programmers, we're taught to use the interface type for our variables because it lets us use any implementation type, not just a specific one. But in the case of putting a list into a `Bundle`, you *need* a specific implementation type. So just go ahead and use that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I wonder if it makes more sense to just put in that 1 cast vs changing the List everywhere, beacuse you said it works as well right?

Comment: Yeah, the cast will work just fine... as long as no one ever assigns a non-`ArrayList` implementation of `List` to that variable. I wouldn't go rewriting your entire codebase just to switch to declaring it as an `ArrayList` up front, but normally I'd expect you only to have to change it in one spot.

Comment: OK when we can't change it to another List anyways, then it really makes no sense to declare it as a List.